# What should I do if the desktop is off the monitor?

Tags: xorg, display, lxde, tv, framebuffer

I have a Samsung Series 7 LED TV that I've hooked up to a computer. But my problem is: When I start Lubuntu, the second the framebuffer initializes, it goes off screen. I disabled the framebuffer, and it works at a tty but in the X server stuff is heavily off screen to the bottom-left. I've tried remaking xorg.conf, and adding a modeline, installing propieratry graphics but all that did was make text gigantic. What should I do?

Comment: What video card and drivers do you use?

Comment: I've used opensource novenua, and nvida-331. The video card is some properitary junk called NVIDA ION, which was all I could get. It's a OEM build and the name is Acer Aspire Revo 3610. The TV is a Samsung series 7 LED tv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used gtf to make a modeline and add it to xorg.conf, I rebooted and it didn't work but there was a new monitor entry: 1680x1050. I changed it to that, saved it, edited xorg.conf and grub.conf by changing the modeline in xorg.conf, and GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_KEEPRES=true or something like that and changed the grub res and now it works!

**EDIT:** The fonts were still gigantic so I added: 
      Option "UseEdidDpi" "FALSE"
      Option "DPI" "96 x 96"
to my xorg.conf. I didn't really care for the login screen so I didn't bother with that.